# VBA/Solver Loop Help - Incremental Changes on Objective Value

Tags: vba, loops, solver

I have created and edited a simple macro (code below) which runs solver then copies and pastes the results/data from the affected cells in to the next available blank row in column E.

Currently the objective is set to minimise cell H33 by changing cells J33:P33 with a constraint that the figures in J33:P33 must sum to 1. What I would like to do is loop the macro for a specified number of iterations (e.g. 50) but I want to be able to set cell H33 to a specified value (e.g. 6), run solver, copy & paste as described then loop through but on each loop, the specified value in cell H33 increases incrementally (e.g. by 0.1) on each run.

```
 Sub Test()
 '
 ' Test Macro
 '
 SolverReset
 SolverOk SetCell:="$H$33", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$J$33:$P$33", _
 Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
 SolverAdd CellRef:="$Q$33", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="1"
 SolverSolve True
 Range("E33:P33").Copy
 Sheets("Output").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
 End Sub
```

Comment: add a line at the end:
range("$H$33").value = range("$H$33").value + 0.1

Comment: Thanks for the response.That doesn't work I'm afraid.All that does is replace the contents of cell H33 with the previous value +0.1 and shifts the existing data down one row. I want Solver to run with H33=6 as the objective by changing cells J33:P33 then paste output in to the next available blank row then loops. On each loop, the objective value of H33 set within Solver increases by 0.1 i.e. on the second loop, the objective will be 6.1 achieved by changing the values in J33:P33. The results should be pasted in to the next blank row and then the loops repeats. Next objective H33=6.2

Comment: ah I thought the pasting was already working. maybe add the line I wrote above and then change your paste to this:
Sheets("Output").Range("E33:P33").Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
where i is the iteration in the for loop you add